# Create a link sharable everywhere

Tags: javascript, facebook, meta

I want to share a specific content of my site by way of a link, and I would that when I share it on Facebook, Twitter, Google+, etc., a certain image, title and description will be shown.
It's so easy when I share my site URL because it's sufficient to modify the related **meta tags**, but it is not so trivial do it with a specific content you want share with dedicated image, title, description.

I thought, since these information shall be specified in **meta tags** why not to enclose my content into an **iframe** which contains a simple *html* page with all necessary meta tags?

This way when I try to share my link on a social network the content summary will be filled with my **meta tags** infos.

Have you a smarter solution?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I believe that every social media have different ways to get this information, and some do not even need them (like twitter does not need a picture to a tweet).

And they are always changing how they do it, facebook is an example url parties is being deprecated and they are forcing us to use their api to share / like / whatever.

What you can do is to work with these differences on their own, or get js social plugins to handle it for you.

edit: here are some plugins http://community.paper.li/2012/10/15/top-8-social-media-plugins-for-your-blog-or-website/

Comment: Twitter does not add images, but title and description are considered. I know there are many plugins to share content, but it is not my aim. I need to create a sharable link which points to my content and has own meta tags